# How do I pre-populate a jQuery Datepicker textbox with today's date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, date, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a very simple jQuery Datepicker calendar:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date_pretty").datepicker({ 
    });
});
```

and of course in the HTML...

```
<input type="text" size="10" value="" id="date_pretty"/>
```

Today's date is nicely highlighted for the user when they bring up the calendar, but how do I get jQuery to pre-populate the textbox itself with today's date on page load, without the user doing anything?  99% of the time, the today's date default will be what they want.

Comment: The most popular answer is better that accepted answer. it's better to change the accepted answer.

Comment: my related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25602649/jqueryui-datepicker-differences-between-defaultdate-option-vs-setdate-method

Comment: @ahmadalishafiee (and everyone else).  The currently accepted solution was accepted on 2015-05-07.

Answer (score 580, accepted):

**Update: There are reports this no longer works in Chrome.**

This is concise and does the job (obsolete):

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

This is less concise, utilizing [chaining](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_chaining.asp) allows it to work in chrome (2019-06-04):

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: This is the one that actually worked for me and not the accepted solution. Thank you

Comment: I would like to suggest if the stackoverflow could just put the top voted answer on top, rather than as it's. E.g like what Youtube did is good.

Comment: +1, using the Date object is much cleaner & bug-proof. Note that you can use things such as `var myDate = new Date(); myDate.setFullYear(1985); myDate.setMonth(0);  /* month is zero-based */ myDate.setDate(28);` see more https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: This will not work, first you should call
$(".date-pick").datepicker();

and then 
$(".date-pick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

Comment: Not longer works in Chrome after recent browser update

Comment: @QuinnDaley Thanks - I'm adding a warning to my answer.

Comment: Works. I'm setting `$(".date-pick").datepicker().datepicker('setDate', new Date()); ` tho

Answer (score 227):

You must FIRST call datepicker() > **then** use 'setDate' to get the current date.

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker();
$(".date-pick").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

OR chain your setDate method call after your datepicker initialization, as noted in a comment on this answer

```
$('.date-pick').datepicker({ /* optional option parameters... */ })
               .datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

It will **NOT** work with just

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

***NOTE*** : *Acceptable setDate parameters are described [here](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)*

Comment: Using jQueryUI 1.8 I found this solution to be the only (sane) way to accomplish this.

Comment: $(".selector").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date()); will work and doesn't make jQuery search the DOM twice.

Comment: Great, accepted answer says only 
$(".date-pick").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
and it doesn't work without first call 
$(".date-pick").datepicker();

your answer is much better

Answer (score 72):

```
var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
        myDate.getFullYear();
$("#date_pretty").val(prettyDate);
```

seemed to work, but there might be a better way out there..

Comment: This works pretty well except for two things:

1) I was kind of hoping to use jQuery method to get the current date, but maybe it doesn't matter.

2) this solution produces a value exactly one month previous to today's date!

Comment: OH - you're right!  check it out - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp - month is 0-11 - you'll have to add 1.. curiously, getDate is 1-31, but getMonth is 0-11..

Comment: There is an easier way .. see my post below.

Comment: This solution let's to show text directly and set date simultaneously while CiscoIPPhone's solution needs another step to show the value without opening the picker.

Comment: For `setDate` you can also use the usual relative notation of datepicker, for example to get the following day just type `.datepicker('setDate', '+1d')`.

Answer (score 59):

The [`setDate()`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate) method sets the date and updates the associated control. Here is how:

```
$("#datepicker1").datepicker({
    dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd"
}).datepicker("setDate", "0");
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/ZBFFJ/)

As mentioned in documentation, `setDate()` happily accepts the JavaScript Date object, number or a string:

> The new date may be a Date object or a string in the current date
>   format (e.g. '01/26/2009'), a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a
>   string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for
>   weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null to clear the selected
>   date.

In case you are wondering, setting [`defaultDate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) property in the constructor *does not* update the associated control.

Comment: Why is it in your demo it works. When I copy this code into my site the dialog keeps popping up when the pg loads.

Comment: This worked for me - the accepted answer and other options above didn't.

Comment: This is a much, much better solution than any of the above.

Comment: Best answer for this question at the present time although I needed the date format to be "mm-dd-yy" to match the date picker.

Answer (score 26):

Set to ***today***:

```
$('#date_pretty').datepicker('setDate', '+0');
```

Set to ***yesterday***:

```
$('#date_pretty').datepicker('setDate', '-1');
```

And so on with any number of days ***before*** or ***after*** *today's date*.

See [jQuery UI › Methods › setDate](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#methods).

Comment: Great, as others have mentioned, you must have called datepicker() once already so, `$(".date-pick").datepicker("setDate", '+0');`

Comment: This also worked as I wished, since my dateFormat needs to match MySQL's date format (yy-mm-dd). This setDate adds zero padding to the month and day.

Answer (score 9):

The solution is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#date_pretty").datepicker({ 
    });
    var myDate = new Date();
    var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var prettyDate = month + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
    $("#date_pretty").val(prettyDate);
});
```

Thanks grayghost!

Answer (score 7):

This one worked for me.

```
$('#inputName')
  .datepicker()
  .datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Answer (score 6):

This code will assure to use your datepicker's format:

```
$('#date-selector').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

No need to re-apply format, it uses the datepicker predefined-one by you on datepicker initialization (if you have assigned it!) ;)

Answer (score 5):

David K Egghead's code worked perfectly, thank you!

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker(); 
$(".date-pick").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

I also managed to trim it a little and it also worked:

```
$(".date-pick").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$('input[name*="date"]').datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        beforeShow: function(input, instance) { 
            $(input).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to set the datepicker to a certain default time (the current date in my case) on loading, AND then have the option to choose another date the syntax is :

```
    $(function() { 
        // initialize the datapicker
        $("#date").datepicker();

        // set the time
        var currentDate = new Date();
        $("#date").datepicker("setDate",currentDate);

    //  set the options for the button  
        $("#date").datepicker("option",{
            dateFormat: 'dd/mm',
            showOn: "button",
          // whatever option Or event you want 
        });
  });
```

Comment: this solution worked for me in chrome, others listed here did not

Answer (score 2):

You've got 2 options:

**OPTION A)**  Marks as "active" in your calendar, only when you click in the input.

**Js**:

```
$('input.datepicker').datepicker(
                        {   
                            changeMonth: false,
                            changeYear: false,
                            beforeShow: function(input, instance) { 
                                $(input).datepicker('setDate', new Date());
                            }
                        }                         
                     );
```

**Css**:

```
div.ui-datepicker table.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active,
        div.ui-datepicker table.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-widget-content .ui-state-active  {
            background: #1ABC9C;
            border-radius: 50%;
            color: #fff;
            cursor: pointer;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 24px; height: 24px;
        }​
```

**OPTION B)** Input by default with today.
You've to populate first the datepicker .

```
$("input.datepicker").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Comment: option A is good because date picker can remain blank until a date is to be selected at which point it defaults to the current date

Answer (score 1):

Just thought I'd add my two cents. The picker is being used on an add/update form, so it needed to show the date coming from the database if editing an existing record, or show today's date if not. Below is working fine for me:

```
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    <?php if (!empty($oneEVENT['start_ts'])): ?>
       $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "setDate", "<?php echo $startDATE; ?>" );
    <? else: ?>
       $("#datepicker").datepicker('setDate', new Date());   
    <?php endif; ?>
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

To pre-populate date, first you have to initialise datepicker, then pass setDate parameter value.

```
$("#date_pretty").datepicker().datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var prettyDate = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd-M-yy', new Date());
alert(prettyDate);
```

Assign the prettyDate to the necessary control.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(this).datepicker("destroy").datepicker({
            changeMonth: false, changeYear: false,defaultDate:new Date(), dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",  showOn: "focus", yearRange: "-5:+10"
        }).focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works better for me as sometimes I have troubles calling `.datepicker('setDate', new Date());` as it messes if if i have the datepicker already configured with parameters.

```
$("#myDateText").val(moment(new Date()).format('DD/MM/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This:

`$(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy' }).datepicker('setDate', new Date());`

To Get Date in Format Eg: 10-Oct-2019 which will be more understandable for users.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(function()
{
$('.date-pick').datePicker().val(new Date().asString()).trigger('change');
});
```

Source: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerDefaultToday.html

Comment: My browser did not recognise the asString() function.
I did it like this: $(".date-pick").datepicker('setDate', new Date());

Comment: I think asString() should be toString().

Comment: Kevin Luck's DatePicker and the Jquery UI DatePicker are two very different datepickers.

Comment: @gamerzfuse jQuery UI’s datepicker is based on that of Kevin Luck.