# How to get current date using jquery?

Tags: jquery, date, jquery-plugins

I am using a calender plug-in and I want to populate the current date into a text field. How can I do this using jquery?

Comment: what calendar plugin? can you show us the link?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can get [current date in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date):

```
var now = new Date();
```

If you are using jQuery [DatePicker](http://marcgrabanski.com/articles/jquery-ui-datepicker) you can apply it on any textfield like this:

```
$('input.youTextFieldClass').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy', 
                                     changeMonth: true,
                                     changeYear: true,
                                     yearRange: '-70:+10',
                                     constrainInput: false,
                                     duration: '',
                                     gotoCurrent: true});
```

[If you want to set current date in textfields as page load:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date)

```
$("input.youTextFieldClass").datepicker('setDate', new Date());
```

Comment: Throw a tag name on that selector and it will run faster.  Replace `'.youTextFieldClass'` with `'input.youTextFieldClass'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the sample [here](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/prQkR/).

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker">
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({dateFormat:"dd M yy"}).datepicker("setDate",new Date());
```