# jQuery UI: Set default date for *inline* datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, uidatepicker

I am using jQuery UI for an *[inline](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#inline)* datepicker. By simply calling it on a `<div>` I get a nice inline datepicker, but I do not see how I can set the default date that is to be selected.

JS:

`$("div.date").datepicker({});`

HTML:

`<div class="date"></div>`

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using the [`defaultDate`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate) option? From the docs:

> Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.
>
> Code examples
>
> Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `$('div.date').datepicker( "setDate" , date);` or you can set the default prior to opening as displayed by Justin Ethier