# jQuery date picker manipulations

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have two datepickers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( '#startdatepicker' ).datepicker();
    });
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function() {
        jQuery( '#enddatepicker' ).datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

How can I modify to it so that the default date is today's date for both the date pickers?

I'd like it if the start date is picked to a different date, allow end date to be picked >= the start date.  If the end date is modified first, allow the start date to be <= to end date.

```
<td align='center'>Start Date:<input type='text' name='start_date' id='startdatepicker' /></td>
<td align='center'>End Date: <input type='text' name='end_date' id='enddatepicker'  /></td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the options of the datepicker plugin. [jQuery date picker manipulations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12849658/jquery-date-picker-manipulations)

You can also try looking at the previously asked stack overflow question: [How do I pre-populate a jQuery Datepicker textbox with today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date)

Here is the sample code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#startdatepicker").datepicker({ 
    });
    var myDate = new Date();
    var month = myDate.getMonth() + 1;
    var prettyDate = month + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' + myDate.getFullYear();
    $("#startdatepicker").val(prettyDate);
});
```