# Setting 'option' on jqueryui DatePicker clears the textbox's value?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I've highlighted the example here:

http://jsfiddle.net/aDxeE/

Basically, a separate event (not known at construction) needs to set `"option","maxDate"` on the datepicker control. This 'clears' the textbox value which is really annoying, as the initial construction does not.

Can anyone offer a solution?

Edit:

Changing line 5 to:

```
$("#myinput").datepicker("destroy");
$("#myinput").datepicker({minDate:new Date(), maxDate: new Date()});
```

makes it work as expected, but is a seriously messy approach.

Comment: @AtifMohammedAmeenuddin I'm using firefox...you're telling me when that page loads the textbox value is still 'dd-mm-yyyy'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an issue with the format. Your initial value `dd-mm-yyyy` doesn't match the datepickers default format. To resolve, set the initial value to the correct format and specify the format as `dateFormat` when creating the datepicker.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Nf7Cs/1/)

Change to:

```
<input id="myinput" type="text" value="01-01-1970" />
```

And:

```
//construct datepicker
$("#myinput").datepicker({minDate:new Date(), dateFormat : "dd-mm-yy"});
//later on, a seperate event changes the maxDate property
//but this 'clears' the existing value in the textbox!
$("#myinput").datepicker("option","maxDate", new Date());
```

Comment: The value set to 'dd-mm-yyyy' is just an example of default text, it might as well say 'hello world'. Same problem is exhibited. See http://jsfiddle.net/aDxeE/7/

Comment: When you update the maxDate option, the current value is evaulated to see if it meets the min and max requirements, it isn't a valid date and so is removed. For default options that aren't valid dates you can use a `placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"` attribute, or put a label next to it.

Comment: I did not know about the `placeholder` attribute, completely new to me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
$("#myinput").datepicker('destroy').datepicker({maxDate:new Date()});
```

- Removes the datepicker functionality completely. This will return the element back to its pre-init state.
- Again re-initiate the datepicker with setting the `maxdate` option.

[**FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/aDxeE/4/)

**UPDATE**

Formated the code for the readability purpose:-

```
$("#myinput").datepicker("destroy");

$("#myinput").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date(),
    maxDate: new Date()
});
```

Comment: This is the only example that works, and as per my edit is a bit messy looking!

Comment: I like this example, and I wouldve marked it as the answer, especially for the sake of backwards compatability, if it wasnt for the html 5 'placeholder' attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try to give it in  `$(document).ready(function(){..});`

```
//construct datepicker
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#myinput").datepicker({minDate:new Date()});
//later on, a seperate event changes the maxDate property
//but this 'clears' the existing value in the textbox!
});
$("#myinput").datepicker("option","maxDate", new Date());
```

Check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/aDxeE/1/).

**FYI:** use placeholder instead of value `placeholder="dd-mm-yyyy"`

Comment: That doesnt work - you realise line 7 doesnt do anything as it's called before line 3

Answer (score 0):

How about manually setting it back again?

```
var d = $("#myinput").val();
$("#myinput").datepicker("option", "maxDate", "+2d").val(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

This question was already answered here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/8945264/2050459

You need to **set** the date first trough code(using setDate) or by opening the datepicker(user interaction).

Here is how you would do it with code : [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rusln/KjXLL/)

```
$("#myinput").datepicker({
    minDate: new Date()
});
$("#myinput").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

In your example, try opening the datepicker and then trigger an event to set a maxDate, you'll see that the input will not be cleared because an active date has been set.

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question.

Comment: The reason that your input is being cleared is because no date is being set. I'm actually explaining you the reason behind your problem. I've just show you how to solve the problem using the datepicker api without using any hacks.

Answer (score -1):

Jqueryui DatePicker clears the textbox's value?

```
myinput = ID of datapicker

$("#myinput").val('');
```