# MVC data annotations not showing default date

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want the EndDate text box to show today's date as default date, but I am seeing mm/dd/yyyy and a arrow (which on clicking shows calendar) in the textbox:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]        
[DisplayName("End Date")]
public string EndDate { get; set; }

$(document).ready(function () {       
$('.date1').datepicker();

@Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndDate, new { @class = "date1" })
```

Comment: When you create your model object, do you set a value for EndDate?

Comment: Also, see this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date?rq=1

Comment: Yes I tried setting the value from the controller :                  dp.EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");

Comment: Using 
dp.EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd"); 
instead of
 dp.EndDate = DateTime.Now.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
worked.

Comment: Good. If you fixed the problem you can answer&accept your own question.