# mvc4 jscript Change button caption based on row data multiple values

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc-4

Many JScript questions are related to changes upon click, I need to react to the row data.

I have a table with several rows that have 3 date values which may be null and are sequential; start, end and certified.

I want to have a single button on each row, and want to change the caption (and possibly the button value and row colors(4) also).  The button info will tell the controller which of the dates to update to "now".

I have this untested JScript:

```
function changeBname(SStart, SEnd, SCert)..and a similar function for the button value
{
  if(SStart == null) { 
    bname ="Start Step"; 
  }
  else  if (SEnd == null) {
    bname ="End Step";
  }
  else if SCert == null) { 
    bname ="Certify Step";
  }
   return
}
```

The idea is that if a row has start and end dates the button's caption will be "Certify Step", if all dates are null the caption will be "Start Step". etc.

5 questions;-I'm a newbie.
-Is this the best way to handle the button? Correct concept?
-Is the Jscript correct?
-In the table row how do I reference the function? My current try-

```
<input type="button" name = changeBname(@item.SStart,@item.SEnd,@item.SCert) >
```

gives a button with the caption -changeBname- not "End Step".

-Where do I put the code to change the color?
-Is there event I could use when the foreach has the row data? (my vb days are showing)-

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you should put a class on the 3 different date fields that you can use for a selector.  date from here [How do I pre-populate a jQuery Datepicker textbox with today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date)

```
var myDate = new Date();
var prettyDate =(myDate.getMonth()+1) + '/' + myDate.getDate() + '/' +
    myDate.getFullYear();
$(document).ready(function () {      
   $('#resultTable tr').click(function () {
       if($(this).closest("td").find(".date1").val() != "")
       {
           $(this).closest("td").find(".date2").val(prettyDate);  
           $(this).closest("td").find(".btnClass").attr("Name", "End Step");        
       }
   });
});
```

this is a click event on the table row instead of just the button but hopefully this will give you the start you need.  let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Yes that will help-but it begs another question- How do I "call" the function within the td construct? currently I have the <input type etc>. Could I do something to call my function and return the entire proper <input type construct>? In my VB days I'd just say call changeBname but html won't accept that @Matt

Comment: Could I do something with a custom helper? Over my head for now, but if I can call a function or put my code in it, I can do that.

Comment: with what I put here the button is just extra.  My code will fire if they click anywhere on the table row.  If you would like to restrict that to just the button you can google button click on table row which will just change the .click row.  the rest of the code should still be valid

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working.
Create this helper in the view:

```
@helper   specialbutton( System.DateTime? SStart, System.DateTime? SEnd, System.DateTime? SCert)
{  
if (SStart == null)
{ <input type = "button" name ="Start Step" value ="start step"> }
else if (SStart != null && SEnd == null)
{ <input type = "button" value ="End Step" > }
else if (SEnd != null && SCert == null)
{<input type = "button" value = "Start Step"> }
}
```

then in my table row:

```
@specialbutton( item.SStart, item.SEnd, item.SCert)
```

It works but notice that I have assigned the value to the caption. When I tried name="Start Step" value = 0  the caption was "0" not "Start Step". As long as this value will be passed to my controller onclick I can work with this, but I'm curious why the name did not work.