# Changing To Date when From date is entered

Tags: javascript, datetimepicker

I have a Fields. One is **ValidFrom** Date and the other is **ValidTo** Date.

My question is what should I do so that if **ValidFrom** date is entered using **DateTimePicker**, how should I change the **ValidTo** by exactly 30 days automatically?

Following is My code for **DateTimePicker**:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ValidFrom').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date(),
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                var date = new Date($input.val());
                date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
                $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker({
                    datepicker: true,
                    timepicker: false,
                    format: 'm/d/Y',
                    step: 30,
                    minDate: date,
                });
            },

        });

    });
</script>
```

> I have to change the ValidTo date by 30 days as and when ValidFrom
>   date is entered.

Comment: Are you getting any error while on changing "validFrom" date-time picker?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pre-populate a jQuery Datepicker textbox with today's date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233553/how-do-i-pre-populate-a-jquery-datepicker-textbox-with-todays-date)

Comment: Can you create a working jsfiddle example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how the code should be like: Got done with it after number of tries

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#ValidFrom').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date(),
            onChangeDateTime: function (dp, $input) {
                var date = new Date($input.val());
                date.setMonth(date.getMonth() + 1);
                date = (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' + date.getFullYear();
                $('#ValidTo').val(date);
            },

        });
        $('#ValidTo').datetimepicker({
            datepicker: true,
            timepicker: false,
            format: 'm/d/Y',
            step: 30,
            minDate: new Date()
        });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing you're looking for is set under `setDate()` method of datetimepicker JS, it can take parameter as `setDate(new Date())`. You can fill your own date (format as required) in the argument of it. If you want no other date to get selected prior to your 30 days limit, you can check for `start` or `startDate` parameters in the same JS.

I suggest you to read datetimepicker.js that you're currently using to get to know about all of its features and parameters